# C# get => modify => set paradigm. how to shorter it into one line function call?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-3.5

So I use something like:

```
...
var o = myclass.o; // o is a property and o is a structure not class
o.modifyInternalParameter(a, b, c); // a, b, c were created somewhere before
myclass.o = o; // as you can see o has getter and setter.
...
```

how to create a functional wrapper to rather than call 3 code lines call some

```
func(myclass.o, TypeOfO.modifyInternalParameter, {a, b, c}, returnValueIfmodifyInternalParameterHasOne);
```

?

Comment: This isn't even valid C# code.

Comment: Is the inner object a struct i.e. by-value semantics? If not, you could directly invoke yourclass.o.Modify(params) to modify the inner object. If it is, then you can code up a yourclass.ModifyO(params) that wraps the three lines internally.

Answer (score 0):

I would have `modifyInternalParameter` return itself or make a static method to do that for you, then you could write something like:

(returning itself, well, copy of itself, but the modified copy)
`myclass.o = myclass.o.modifyInternalParameter(a, b, c)`

(static)
`myclass.o = ModifyInternalParameters(myclass.o, a, b, c)`

So your internal method might look like:

```
public MyStruct modifyInternalParameter(object a, object b, object c)
{
    this.A = a;
    this.B = b;
    this.C = c;
    return this;
}
```

Can do something similar with the static version.

EDIT: You could also create an extension method (or a method on `myclass`) do to this for you internally:

`myclass.ModifyInternalParametersOnO(a, b, c)`

Where you might have:

```
public static void ModifyInternalParametersOnO(this MyClass myclass, object a, object b, object c)
{
    var o = myclass.o;
    o.modifyInternalParameters(a, b, c);
    myclass.o = o;
}
```